# how to remove hidden junk character after php json encode

Tags: php, android, ios, arrays, json

I was created JSON array from `json_encode` using PHP. I gave my array to `json_encode` .  It's created JSON array very well. And i feed this JSON array to my android apps. When i am gonna read this url at android it's return following EXCEPTION ERROR.

```
Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value ï»¿ of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

But when i am gonna create jason object at android adding this following line

```
jObj=new JSONObject(json.substring(json.indexOf("{"), json.lastIndexOf("}") + 1));
```

It's working perfectly.

But i don't want to need the my second type solution. I need the php solution when i am put my json_encode on php.

And also at IOS the JSON return NULL values. How can i fix in both IOS and Android

Thanks advance

Answer (score 1):

The [`java.text.Normalizer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/Normalizer.html) is intended to do exactly this: remove unwanted unicode characters.

The [`normalize`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/Normalizer.html#normalize%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.text.Normalizer.Form%29) method will allow you to pass your `CharSequence` and return the "normalized", ASCII-only `String`.

Comment: @tamil_arvu he just added two(2) links for you to read. So follow them and enjoy your reading.

Comment: thanks my friend, they all described about how to remove unwanted unicode from string not an array. i give my php array to json_encode it's also php function. here how can i use Normalize ?? and i need this on php side not java.